# testng problems writing results to test-output

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

Can someone explain what needs to change in Eclipse to resolve the following TestNG reporting issues?

After updating Eclipse MARS.2 TestNG plug-in to 6.9.11.201604020423, TestNG displays messages showing problems with writing the results:

> [Utils] Problem creating output directory C:\the\project\path\test-output\old\Default suite
>   [Utils] Attempting to create C:\the\project\path\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html
>   [Utils]   Directory C:\the\project\path\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true

Comment: Thank you Murali for a very clear response.  Unfortunately the testNG [Utils] messages are still displayed on the console at the end of the test run. I will retry your suggestion. I'd also like to try installing the previous version of the testNG plug-in.  Can you tell me how to download the older testNG?

Answer (score 1):

the log you mentioned is the TestNG debug log, this got fixed in ticket: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/253, which set the default logging verbose log to 0 (means disabled)

you can install the [latest beta of testng-eclipse](http://testng.org/doc/download.html) if you don't want to wait for the release.

Answer (score 0):

Try once by uninstalling the testng and reinstalling from marketplace.

[Here](http://www.ufthelp.com/2014/12/uninstall-pluginaddin-in-eclipse.html) is the steps to uninstall the testng plugin.

After uninstall close the eclipse and start eclipse freshly by cleaning.

> Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory
>   and insert -clean as the first line.

After that install testng from Help>>Market place.

Note: dont forget to update your eclipse.ini by removing added -clean otherwise it always start cleanly which will take some time.